# ¿Como actualizar lista de Observables en Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

Tengo una app Movil con 3 listas de tareas (Disponibles, Pendientes, En curso), dichas tareas esta en un listView cada una respectivamente y estos listView en un Frame cada una, todo dentro de un RefreshView:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MvTareas/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<RefreshView Command="{Binding RefrescarCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding EsRefrescando}">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10">
                    <Label Text="{Binding nombre}"  FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
            <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" HeightRequest="300">

                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <!-- Título -->
                    <Label Text="Tareas Disponibles" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Lista}" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                        .....

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" HeightRequest="300">

                <StackLayout>
                    <!-- Título -->
                    <Label Text="Tareas Pendientes" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaTareasPendientes}" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell >
                                    .....
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
            <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10" HeightRequest="300">

                <StackLayout>
                    <!-- Título -->
                    <Label Text="Tareas en Curso" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="0,0,0,10" />
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListaTareasCurso}" HasUnevenRows="True"  >
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell >
                                    .....
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </StackLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</RefreshView>
```

El caso es que tengo 3 botones uno para aceptar tarea disponible, otro para iniciar tarea pendiente y otro para finalizar tarea en curso. Pero no logro actualizar la lista de tareas automaticamente. Lo que tengo son 3 listas observables y un icommand que llama a un metodo actualizarTareas():

```
public class MvTareas : INotifyPropertyChanged

{
    public static ICommand RefrescarCommand { get;private set; }

    private bool _esRefrescando;

    public bool EsRefrescando
    {
        get { return _esRefrescando; }
        set
        {
            if (_esRefrescando != value)
            {
                _esRefrescando = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EsRefrescando));
            }
        }
    }
    public string nombre {  get; set; }
     
    private ObservableCollection<Tarea> _lista;

    public ObservableCollection<Tarea> Lista
    {
        get { return _lista; }
        set
        {
            if (_lista != value)
            {
                _lista = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Lista));
            }
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Tarea> _listaC;

    public ObservableCollection<Tarea> ListaTareasCurso
    {
        get { return _listaC; }
        set
        {
            if (_listaC != value)
            {
                _listaC = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListaTareasCurso));
            }
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Tarea> _listaP;

    public ObservableCollection<Tarea> ListaTareasPendientes
    {
        get { return _listaP; }
        set
        {
            if (_listaP != value)
            {
                _listaP = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ListaTareasPendientes));
            }
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Esas son las propiedades de la clase y este es el constructor y el metodo:

```
        public MvTareas()
        {
            this.nombre = "Hola" + Preferences.Get("usuario", "");
            Lista = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
            ListaTareasPendientes = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
            ListaTareasCurso = new ObservableCollection<Tarea>();
            RefrescarCommand = new Command(ActualizarTareas);
            obtenerTareas(Preferences.Get("idAgente", "")); 
            obtenerTareasP(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
            obtenerTareasC(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));


        }
        private void ActualizarTareas()
        {
            EsRefrescando = true;
            appNotificacionesPush.App2.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("actualizando", "ok", "ok");

this.nombre= "Hola" + Preferences.Get("usuario", "");
            // Llama a la función para obtener nuevas tareas
            obtenerTareas(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
           obtenerTareasP(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));
           obtenerTareasC(Preferences.Get("idAgente", ""));


            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                EsRefrescando = false;
            });

        }
```

los metodos de obtener tareas tienen las siguiente firma:

`public async void obtenerTareas(string idAgente)`

el caso es que si deslizo hacia abajo la "ruedita" queda andando y no para.